# How to compute on the fly + download a file - React / Django?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, file, amazon-s3

I am working on an app which uses React and Django. I need a functionality whereby a user on the app can click a button and download a csv file on their machine. Importantly, the file is not already available anywhere, it needs to be generated on the fly when the user requests it (by clicking on the download button).

I am thinking of implementing this flow:

When the user clicks on the button, an API call is made which tells the backend to generate the csv file and store it in an s3 bucket
the backend then sends a response to the frontend which contains the URL that the frontend can access to download the file from the s3 bucket
the file gets downloaded
Would this be a good approach? If not, what is the best practice for doing this?

Comment: Yes, you can create API call to generate the csv file and download it with front end.

Answer (score 1):

To let a user download a file you can simply use the `a` tag

```
<a href="/path/to/generate/file.csv" download>
```

I would make the button act like a link and add use the url to your api that creates the file. You backend should then create the file and can respond with it directly.

If the generation is costly you could upload it to a fileserver that you could use to serve the file a second time if the user wants to download the file again. But then you will have other things to consider, e.g. updating the file if anything changes and how do you check if a file is already created.

Would never recommend you sharing a link directly to your fileserver, always let it pass through your api.

Comment: Thanks! So you think sending the link to the s3 file to the front end and using that in the button's href would be bad practice?

If so, how would you make the <a href="url_here"> dynamic? i.e. what would go into the "href" if not the url pointing to the file in the s3 bucket?

Comment: Depending on how you configure your links it could be completely fine to share them directly, however it looks more professional if you proxy them through your api.  
The url that you should put in the "href" should be the url to your api that generate/fetch a file from s3. By just having one endpoint for this, you can control if you just want to generate the file everytime or if you want to store it on a fileserver. And you can move the fileserver without invalidation all other links. Hope this make senes, let me know otherwise and I could try to expand my answer.